# Changing the cell range of conditional formatting in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Is there any way of changing the *range* of conditional formatting in LibreOffice Calc (version 3.6)? I have a set applied already to a range of cells, but there is no obvious way of changing which cells a given set of conditional formatting is applied to. I either have to copy and paste the formatting, which results in multiple entries in the conditional formatting (which makes it difficult to manage), or delete the entire thing and create a new one every single time I want to change the range of cells.

Is there a better way?

[image: Cell range formatting]

Comment: Have you tried using the format painter? I don't know if it would help.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you put a large area to your range?

Try to tag the whole sheet and add a new conditional format.
The range will be **A1:ZX9999999** or so.

Comment: Well, I don't want it applied to the whole sheet. If I did it that way, I'd have to add additional logic to each rule to limit the range, which is a bit of a hassle. Every single rule would need to be wrapped in loads of additional logic just to limit the range to which it is being applied.

Answer (score 0):

There is no optimal way in 3.6; the options to [extend a conditional range](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/7778/modify-existing-conditional-formatting-range-in-calc/?answer=11013#post-id-11013) are Paste Special (format), the Format Paintbrush (in the Standard toolbar by default, next to the edit buttons), and editing context.xml in the archive file (open it in an archive utility that allows editing contained files, or change the extension to "zip"). The former two will create a separate conditional formatting entry for each cell.

Starting in version 4.0, the range can be edited from the conditional formatting dialog:

1. From the dialog shown ("Manage Conditional Formatting"), select the formatting you want to change.
2. Click the "Edit" button to open the conditional formatting dialog.
3. At the bottom of the dialog should be a "Cell Range" text input. Edit the range manually or by selecting the new range of cells (move the dialog out of the way, or use the "Shrink" button to view more of the spreadsheet).
   [image: Conditional Formatting range]
4. Click the "OK" button to save.